# Setting WinRE (Windows Recovery Environment) Flag On Partitions

Tags: windows, partitioning, clone, windows-re

[In AOMEI Partition Assistant I have cloned multiple partitions of one hard drive to another](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4BL6X.png), however, the WRE flags have not been carried over, even when MSR and EFI have.

Is there any way to set WRE flags or is this even something that would have any effect on using WRE on the laptop the cloned HD will later be connected to?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: For MBR Recovery Partition: `set id=27` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61051905/recovery-partition-id-cannot-be-set-on-primary-partition

Answer (score 25, accepted):

- Run `diskpart`
- Make sure of the correct disk number by running `list disk` command.
- Run `select disk X` where `X` is the number of cloned disk.
- Make sure of the correct WinRE partition(s) number by running `list partition` command.
- `select partition Y` where `Y` is the number of WinRE partition.
- Run `set id="de94bba4-06d1-4d40-a16a-bfd50179d6ac"` to set Recovery Flag on the partition.

  *(Optional): to provide more protection on partition Run `gpt attributes=0x8000000000000001`. This attribute is cumulative and the sum of `0x0000000000000001` (set as required partition by system) and `0x8000000000000000` (prevent assigning drive letter automatically on new machines).*
- Repeat last 2 steps for each of the additional WinRE partitions.

*Note:* **Just for your consideration**, you can also do this on MBR disks by running `set id=27`.

**Update:**

If you've accidentally set Recovery Partition ID (or any other ID) on a partition by mistake, to convert it to a normal partition again:

*On an MBR Disk:*

```
select disk X
select partition Y
set id=7
```

*On a GPT Disk:*

```
select disk X
select partition Y
set id="ebd0a0a2-b9e5-4433-87c0-68b6b72699c7"
```

Where `0x07` and `ebd0a0a2-b9e5-4433-87c0-68b6b72699c7` are partition type IDs for normal partitions respectively on MBR and GPT disks. (You can find it as the first item in the [last link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365449(VS.85).aspx) called `PARTITION_BASIC_DATA_GUID`. also for MBR see [3rd link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_type)).

**Sources:**

*MBR Disks (BIOS installation):*

- [Configure BIOS/MBR-Based Hard Drive Partitions](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh825146.aspx)
- [Sample: Configure BIOS/MBR-Based Hard Disk Partitions by Using Windows PE and DiskPart](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh825677.aspx)
- [MBR Partition Type ID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_type)

*GPT Disks (UEFI installation):*

- [Configure UEFI/GPT-Based Hard Drive Partitions](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh824839.aspx)
- [Sample: Configure UEFI/GPT-Based Hard Drive Partitions by Using Windows PE and DiskPart](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh825686.aspx)
- [GPT Partition ID and Attributes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365449(VS.85).aspx)

Comment: So this flagged that partition properly, but it doesn't seem to allow me to boot into recovery on that partition still... also still can't create recovery media from that partition. I did the same thing as OP, cloning from one drive to another (I used EaseUS cloner), and this is the one thing that doesn't seem to work quite right.

Comment: For people coming from search engines, it would really help this answer to either include or link to instructions on turning a brand new partition into a recovery partition (this is where I'm stuck, I know winre.wim is included in the installation media but after that I'm lost)