# Move Windows Recovery from C: onto its Own Recovery Partition

Tags: windows, partitioning, windows-re

While setting up this home Windows installation some months back I managed to end up without a recovery partition for complicated reasons I won't get into, but I'd like to have it back. I have ~1000MBish unallocated at the end of my main drive to turn into the RE partition.

I have seen a lot of suggestions to just do an in-place upgrade from installation media, which is *supposed* to conjure up a recovery partition on its own, but I've also seen [reports](https://www.elevenforum.com/t/deleted-windows-recovery-partition-how-to-make-a-new-one.11534/post-238332) that this doesn't always work and I am just not willing to chance it.

I can enable/disable RE on C: using `reagentc /enable` and `reagentc /disable` which happily moves `Winre.wim` between `..\System32\Recovery\` when disabled and `C:\Recovery\WindowsRE\` when enabled.

I have, in preparation, created a partition in the unallocated space as such:

```
> diskpart
> create partition primary
> format quick fs=ntfs label="Windows RE tools"
> assign letter="R"
```

My problem is I am unsure how to tell reagentc to deploy the files to this partition when enabling. (and will removing the drive letter then break it or will it use the internal GUID?)

I have found this [excellent answer here](https://superuser.com/a/1109582/1140637) that tells us all about ensuring that proper ID and attributes are set on the partition, which is great for once the RE is actually in the right place.

For clarity this is a GPT disk, currently there is a ~3720GB C: part, a 260MB EFI partition, and the new R: on the end.

Side Q: can I delete `C:\Recovery` dir when recovery is on a separate partition, or does Windows throw a tantrum?

Comment: You can use DISM to apply the Windows image to the partition.

Comment: @Ramhound could you explain further? I don't know how to do that. Is the result the same the recovery partition you'd normally have in a fresh install?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Windows 10 lacks partitions and WinRe options](https://superuser.com/questions/1514856/windows-10-lacks-partitions-and-winre-options)

Comment: No better than my answer, I don't think. I really don't like how they choose to manually take several steps that REAgentC is designed to do automatically. If you have extremely specific needs then I imagine it is helpful, but for the majority of home use cases my answer here involves far fewer steps and less legwork e.g. manually moving files around and creating the structure by hand. There is no need to personally access the partition afaik unless you're doing something very niche or something has gone *very* wrong. Linking to that answer could certainly help people in dire straits however.

Comment: @ch4rl1e97 It's about this question being a direct duplicate of another

Comment: Considering they're asking about bitlocker, a different PC environment (EFI/GPT vs BIOS), and totally lacking recovery options as opposed to this case of *having* recovery options but the recovery boot files simply being in the "wrong" place, I think these questions are related but not direct duplicates, and I would suggest at minimum for searchability reasons having both questions available does not do the community harm. I spent hours searching and never found that question previously.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right, turns out I was very close.

After creating my extra space at the end and formatting/naming it, the only job remaining is to just set the ID. REAgentC will *automatically* detect it when enabling! That's what I missed.

Here are full steps with explanations and example output. Skip down to part 8 if you already have freed up some space (At least 700MB-ish).

1. Open an elevated cmd.exe prompt and type...
2. `diskpart`
3. `list disk`

Outputs:

```
  Disk ###  Status         Size     Free     Dyn  Gpt
  --------  -------------  -------  -------  ---  ---
  Disk 0    Online         1863 GB  2048 KB   *    *
  Disk 1    Online         3726 GB      0 B        *
```

In my case, my main drive is Disk 1, so I used:

4. `select disk 1`
5. `list partition`

Outputs:

```
  Partition ###  Type              Size     Offset
  -------------  ----------------  -------  -------
  Partition 1    Reserved            16 MB  1024 KB
  Partition 2    System             260 MB  3723 GB
  Partition 3    Reserved          1000 MB  3724 GB
  Partition 4    Primary           3723 GB    17 MB
```

You will inevitably have different partitions in a different order and different sizes, doesn't matter. You need to identify the largest sized one. this will probably be your main drive (e.g. C:\) that you store things on, so check you have at least a few GB free on your main drive and free some if you don't, or the next step may not work. **In this example we will pick number 4, don't blindly copy this.**

6. `select partition 4`
7. `shrink desired=700`

This will reduce the size of the partition by 700MB, which seems to be a recommended size as of this writing. You can check with `list partition` that there should be 700MB unallocated.

8. `create partition primary`

Outputs:

```
DiskPart succeeded in creating the specified partition
```

9. `format quick fs=ntfs label="winRE"`

Outputs:

```
DiskPart successfully formatted the volume
```

We've filled the empty space (it will use all available space automatically) and formatted it how it needs to be, and given it a nice name. Note when you create a new partition it will automatically select the new partition, so we skipped doing `select partition ...` again.

10. `set id=de94bba4-06d1-4d40-a16a-bfd50179d6ac`

This is a magic ID that tells it that this is a recovery partition. if you now do `list partition` then you will see the "Type" of our new partition is set to "Recovery"!

11. `gpt attributes=0x8000000000000001`

This is two attributes combined,  `0x8000000000000000` "specifies that the partition won't receive a drive letter by default when the disk is moved to another computer, or when the disk is seen for the first time by a computer." Meanwhile `0x0000000000000001` "specifies that the partition is required by the computer to function properly." ([source on attributes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/gpt#parameters))

12. We're done with DiskPart! Type `exit`.
13. `reagentc /disable`
14. `reagentc /enable`

This will turn off and on again the recovery. If you didn't already have it enabled then the first command will tell you, but it's worth checking. REAgentC will automatically detect our new Recovery partition when we `/enable` it and will install the recovery partition in there, instead of on your C:\ drive. Let's double check its in the right place:

15. `reagentc /info`

Outputs (something like):

```
Windows Recovery Environment (Windows RE) and system reset configuration
Information:

    Windows RE status:         Enabled
    Windows RE location:       \\?\GLOBALROOT\device\harddisk1\partition5\Recovery\WindowsRE
    Boot Configuration Data (BCD) identifier: b52d9340-ac37-11ee-b25e-38d57a9b2c2e
    Recovery image location:
    Recovery image index:      0
    Custom image location:
    Custom image index:        0

REAGENTC.EXE: Operation Successful.
```

We're looking to make sure that in the long bit of text near the top, we see `harddisk1` (or whatever disk number you picked earlier, usually 0 for most people), and then `partition5` (the number of our new partition)

Comment: Where is the `winre.wim`? `ReAgentC /enable` won't enable WinRE without the correct folder structure and `winre.wim` on the WinRE partition

Comment: If you didn't notice I answered my own question here, this worked, it is in place, REAgentC appears to have generated the structure as required, hence the `Recovery\WindowsRE` directory structure present in partition5 in the above example under "Windows RE location:". `winre.wim`, when RE is disabled, lives in `%systemroot%\System32\Recovery\`. You can watch it appear and disappear when you disable/enable it.

Comment: I've just triple checked for you and realised I still have a drive letter assigned. With some permissions wrangling I can see that `winre.wim` is present and correct in `R:\Recovery\WindowsRE`! And further, I am able to boot into the recovery environment via the usual advanced boot options.

Comment: AFAIK, `winre.wim` does not usually get copied back to `%WinDir%\System32\Recovery`, unless Microsoft changed this recently, which is why it's recommended to copy it before disabling WinRE. This answer is also missing the correct GPT attributes for the WinRE partition set via `DiskPart`

Comment: Its' definitely the case as of recent at the very least, test it out yourself if you like. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/reagentc-command-line-options?view=windows-11#enable Most of the references I've read on this say the same thing and that's going back at least a few years. Perhaps introduced with Win10 or one of the major updates? I don't have an old machine available to test. Good point about GPT attributes, I'll add that in (though it seems to work without, it will complete the answer)